# Select text based on line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the Weight: & the Weight with box: into 2 variables so I can use elsewhere

The main problem is I can't simply count the number of br's and work off that as they are inconsistent, some will have 4 some will have 6/7 as the information before the weights change... the only thing consistent is the weights and containing class

```
<div class="box">
 Quantity:  1 <br>
 Quantity pack:  10 <br>
 Box (width x length x height):  65x65x120 <br>
 Quantity 2:  2083 <br>
 Pallet :  800x1200x1100 <br>
 Weight:  95 <br>
 Weight with box:  115 <br>
</div>
```

Thanks Guys

Comment: Any reason your data can't be in a table or some other more useful structure?

Comment: Otherwise you'll have to use regular expressions or some other means to find `Weight: ` and key of that and the trailing break tag.

Comment: Don't use breaks, but child div's instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the HTML is not ideal for extracting data. I would suggest you amend it to something more suitable, if possible. If it is not, you can retrieve all text nodes, and then get the final two values - assuming the format of the HTML does not change. Something like this:

```
var nodes = $('.box').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.textContent) != '';
});

var weight = nodes[nodes.length -1];
var weightBox = nodes[nodes.length -2];
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9now1o4o/)

If the order of the properties is not consistent, you would need to loop through the `nodes` array and check for the preceeding `weight:` or `weight with box:` text.

Comment: I like this, it uses the power of DOM traversel by traversing the text nodes instead of using regex.

Comment: Why a fiddle and not a snippet?

Comment: @Mouser personal preference. If I added the snippet I would have had to duplicate all the HTML from the question, even though none of it has changed or is relevant to my answer.

Comment: I got the same thinking but was too slow in fiddling it :) +1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Unfortunately I have no way of changing the data within .box, which would make things so much easier.
Your nodes idea sounds ideal, something I didn't think of 
Thank you very much

Comment: I have one question, related to this. I tried to use regex, to get weight and weight with box: https://regex101.com/r/iT5sA0/1 But, when i tested this regex in jsfiddle, it doesn't work. Non-capturing groups are captured, too, and: http://jsfiddle.net/utg7yzrn/?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution would be to wrap them with something you can identify them with, notice the spans with the ID that you can use to target the nodes with.

```
<div class="box">
 Quantity:  1 <br>
 Quantity pack:  10 <br>
 Box (width x length x height):  65x65x120 <br>
 Quantity 2:  2083 <br>
 Pallet :  800x1200x1100 <br>
 Weight:  <span id="weight">95</span> <br>
 Weight with box:  <span id="weight-box">115</span> <br>
</div>

<script>
var weight = document.getElementById("weight").innerHTML;
</script>
```

See this JS fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/8jduxn1s/

Comment: Unfortunately the main problem is  I have no way of changing the data within .box, which would make things so much easier.